# How can I see or view the pathname which I recently have made?

Tags: windows, cmd, directory, environment

I am doing the course of Zed Shaw "learning python the hard way". In the study there is some kind of command line which create a pathname.

Command Line:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(”Path”, ”$env:Path;C:\Python27”, ”User”)
```

I am nearly close to the answer of this question but how can I make or see those pathnames which I recently has created. As it said that Windows does not always make pathname for a directory how can I see or test if a pathname is created?

This question keep me awake as I am still trying to understand this simple command line:

```
 [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(”Path”, ”$env:Path;C:\Python27”, ”User”)
```

I am figuring out what this command line is saying to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out with a friend of mine.

You can use this [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path") to see your whole pathname.

With [Environment]::SetEnvironment("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27" ( you are making a pathname with the name "Python27")

if you want to replace it you can use this:

Replace: $env:Path.Replace("C:\Python27", "C:\TEST2")

If you want to remove something with "" ( nothing) you can use this :

$newpath = $env:Path.Replace("C:\Python27", "")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $newpath, "User")